# How can terminate the job if some files keep open on windows build machines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

How can I invoke build as failure on file unable open in windows build machines. Actually the build was a success, because of the file opened the job doesn't deploy some of files and finally application is failing.

My requirement is to fail the build if some files keep open. is there any workaround? I see couple open tickets for similar kind of issue.

```
02:26:08 c:\resin-3.1.12\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib\ridl-3.2.1.jar - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
02:26:08 c:\resin-3.1.12\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib\unoil-3.2.1.jar - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Comment: I can search for the text using 'Text-finder' plugin and mark the build as 'UNSTABLE'. However it's not a good idea I guess.